# Why can't I make a row of rectangles in different colors when using a loop?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, canvas

I just started learning Python, so I thought that to create a chessboard would be a great place to start. I found that "tkinter" would be nice to use if I want to make graphics.
To create a row of squares I thought it would be clever to make a loop (I used a "while" loop), which I did. Everything worked fine until I wanted to make the squares have to different colors: white and grey. When I then ran the code, I would only get one square in one color, and one long rectangle which had the other color.

As I said, I am new to Python so I have no clue why it won't work.
Here is the code:

```
root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=800)
canvas.pack()
j=1
i=1
x=0
y=0
l=100
b=l

color = "white"

while j < 10:
    kvadrat1 = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, l, b, fill=color),
    if j % 2 == 0:
        color = "grey"
    else:
        color ="white" 
    j=j+1
    x=x+100


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You never change `y`, so there won't be any squares next to each other horizontally (which you probably don't want).

Comment: In addition, the 2nd set of coords (l , b) in your code are the lower right coordinates - which you are not changing.  Try logging the parameters to `create_rectangle` on each iteration and post.  Also, due to your logic, the 1st rectangle is white, the 2nd rectangle is white and then it alternates.

Comment: Of course! I should have seen that, thanks, Andy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the tkinter docs, you'll see that `createRectangle`'s first 4 parameters are x1, x2, y1, and y2 as coordinates, not x1, x2, width, height.

To draw squares of 100 pixels side lengths, you should call `createRectangle(x, y, x+100, y+100, fill=color)`

There is another bug with your code though, which is that the first two squares are both white...This is because color starts out as white, and then during the first loop iteration, it sets the color to white again. To fix this, you can either reverse the conditions or start off by setting color = "grey" initially.

```
root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=800)
canvas.pack()
j=1
i=1
x=0
y=0
l=100
b=l

color = "grey"

while j < 10:
    print(j, color)
    kvadrat1 = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+100, y+100, fill=color),
    if j % 2 == 0:
        color = "grey"
    else:
        color ="white" 
    j=j+1
    x=x+100
root.mainloop()
```

will do the trick.

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 0):

So you have two problems here.

One is that you have misrepresented the parameters of `create_rectangle()` which are two coordinates, not a coordinate and size.

The other is that you should calculate the `color` *before* you create the rectangle:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=800)
canvas.pack()
j=1
i=1
x=0
y=0
l=100
b=l

while j < 10:
    if j % 2 == 0:
        color = "grey"
    else:
        color ="white" 
    kvadrat1 = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + l, y + b, fill=color)
    j = j + 1
    x = x + 100


root.mainloop()
```